# Trailing solidus not allowed on element link error when I wanted to import external css with link tag in html

Tags: html, css

I made an html file but when I wanted to import my css file trow an error like trailing solidus not allowed on element link. But unlike this everything work fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<title>space atack</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<script src="js/gameplay.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Update 1:
I got the errors.
The error of link tag:
[image: error of link tag]
The lines with errors:
[image: lines with errors]

Update 2:
I am sure for Gamestart.js and the background image load but when I tried to add another element in body in index.html (a paragraf) it not showing. Only elements what I writed in js are showing.

main.css file:

```
#divplay{
  text-align: center;
  top: 45%;
}
#btnplay{
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: yellow;
  width: 40%;
  height: 10%;
}
```

gameplay.js file:

```
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('img/bg/spatiu.jpg')";
var playdiv = document.createElement('div');
playdiv.id = 'divplay'; 
document.body.appendChild(playdiv);
var playbtn =  document.createElement('button');
playbtn.id = 'btnplay';
playbtn.innerHTML = 'play';
playbtn.addEventListener("click", play);
playdiv.appendChild(playbtn);
function play(){
  playbtn.remove();
  playdiv.remove();
}
```

Comment: Are you able to provide the exact error, and which line it occurs on?

Comment: I can try (to explain I am on mobile)

Comment: Please provide the error as it is.

Comment: I got the errors.

Comment: Have you ever tried viewing the HTML as a file? Those errors do not seem like things that would cause serious problems when loaded.

Comment: I tried and yes index.html is in the same folder with the main.css .

Comment: Well did the files load? I assume it would. Check in developer tools, for errors (Ctrl + Shift + I)

Comment: I am sure for Gamestart.js and the background image load but when I tried to add another element in body in index.html (a paragraf) it not showing. Only elements what I writed in js are showing.

Comment: I do not know exatcly what was the problem (I tink it was with my browser) but I writed again the link tag (but I know it was writed correctly) and now it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link element is a self terminating element.

Including a `/` at the end of the element. This should resolve the error.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />`

*^ See example above*

Comment: It still not working

Comment: I do not know exatcly what was the problem (I tink it was with my browser) but I writed again the link tag (but I know it was writed correctly after I put "/" to the end) and now it work. Thank you.